# Javacc Package Problems

Tags: java, package, abstract-syntax-tree, javacc

We are implementing a version of gibberish using javacc to build our abstract syntax tree. We have many classes implemented in java that are called by our Parser.jj program. However, Parser.jj doesn't recognize any of the classes implemented even though they are in the same folder / package (e.g. Error: cannot find symbol: class VariableNode). Is there a way to get Parser.jj to recognize those files?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you adding the appropriate package declaration after PARSER_BEGIN of Parser.jj?

Answer (score 3):

Place your jj file under src/a/b/c/jj

```
PARSER_BEGIN( MyParserGenerator )

package a.b.c.jj;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MyParserGenerator
{
   // Your attributes and methods here       
}
PARSER_END( MyParserGenerator )
```

In Eclipse, right-click, choose Compile and chazam! the 7 sources are here.